# How might I cause jQuery Autocomplete to display results with images, and no PHP?

Tags: jquery, image, autocomplete, input, jquery-autocomplete

I am implementing jQuery Autocomplete and wish to display results with an associated image.  Each image has the same name as the predicted result of the autocomplete field. i.e. If someone types "braz" then "brazil" appears with brazil.jpg inline beside it.  I'm having trouble implementing this.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.  By the way, I'm using [Jorn's version](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/).

Am also interested in using smaller versions of autocomplete, but have only found Drew Wilson's and couldn't manage to work it at all.

Comment: What have you got? Where are you stuck? Can you provide links to the versions you are talking about?

Comment: Ive got jquery auto complete, being fed results from getdata.jsp, ie. $(\"#country\").autocomplete('getdata.jsp');

Version: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: So I can actually get the desired result, displaying country name then flag in predicted results, by editing getdata.jsp to return image ref after country name, but then if country is selected from pedicted list, it will display something like Brazil <img src... in input field when it should just display Brazil.

So I think i need to find another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at `#suggest4` on this [demo page](http://view.jquery.com/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/). The `formatItem` and `formatResult` functions are used to make the result and the item appear different.

```
function formatItem(row) {
    return row[0] + " (<strong>id: " + row[1] + "</strong>)";
}
function formatResult(row) {
    return row[0].replace(/(<.+?>)/gi, '');
}

// apply the format functions using the options provided.
$("#country").autocomplete('getdata.jsp', { 
    formatItem: formatItem,
    formatResult: formatResult
};
```

Comment: ok so i wrote a formatItem function just before line $(\"#country\").autocomplete('getdata.jsp'); . . Next step is what?  Add another param to autocomplete?? Sorry Im new to Jquery and js.

Comment: See my edit. For a full list of options see: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions.

Comment: Just figured that out. As soon as I answered my own question, saw yours.  Cheers Joel